# Problem with init

Tags: org-mode, init-file

Windows 10/ emacs 27.0.50.

I try to use `<s` with `TAB` to expand to a ‘src’ code block in org files. This doesn't work for me with my config.

When I execute Emacs with `-q` (`-no-init-file`) and it does work. But now I can't find problems package in the configuration file. I commented out whole `.emacs`. and tried deleting `.emacs` file, but anyway the behavior is repeated.

I don't have other configuration files (`~/.emacs, ~/.emacs.el, or ~/.emacs.d/init.el`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `emacs -Q` loads old version of `org-mode`. Template expansion was changed in 9.2. See more details in [Release notes](https://orgmode.org/Changes.html). The important quote from that page is

> If you prefer using previous patterns, e.g. `<s`, you can activate them again 
>    by requiring Org Tempo library:
>
> `(require 'org-tempo)`
>
> or add it to `org-modules`

Answer (score 0):

Other than muffinmad's answer I'd like you to examine what `TAB` is bound to in each case:

Do everything up to but not actually hitting `TAB` and hit `C-h` `k` (describe-key) and hit `TAB` at the prompt.

My emacs lists `TAB` is bound to `org-cycle`, is it the same in the working and not working environment of yours?